# VCLibs missing in VS 2012

Tags: windows-runtime, bing

I am using the RTM Bing SDK in RTM VS 2012 on RTM Windows 8.
It works fine on one machine, and I checked in that solution to TFs and checked it out to another machine, with the same configuaration.

On that machine, the compile fails with

Warning               5              Could not find SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=11.0".

And sure enough, when I got to add reference, the MS VC++ Runtime package is not in the list!
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package is NOT in the list of References that I can add with Add Reference, Windows, Extensions.

Where did it go? It is there on my first machine.

I have followed all the steps in the Bing for RT SDK raadme, set the Active Configuration to x86 etc.

Comment: are you building a C# or a c++ app?

Comment: see this for more info on VCLibs http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx